# Different Exceptions when using tomcat remote and local java.net.SocketException SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I'm writing a JUNIT-Test to test a connection to tomcat 7.0.47 over HTTPS/TLSv1.1 with a **corrupted** Client-Certificate.

When I run my test against a remote tomcat everything works fine, I get an `SSLHandshakeException.`

When I run the same test against a local tomcat I get this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

But on the tomcat logs I could see that the request and the client certificate has arrived and was checked in tomcat.

Does anyone have an idea why there are different Exceptions? The configurations and versions of both tomcats are the same.